# Continue script after rescue in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am parsing JSON output by using the curl mentioned below , 
However I am getting `no method error` while parsing the output due to `DESCRIPTION #{h["incident_updates"][1]["status"]` . because  `[["incident_updates"][1][status]]` is not present in some cases, only the values of `[["incident_updates"][0][status]]` is available .

( But others iteration contains values for both `[0][status]`
 `[1][status]`  )

So to avoid the error used `rescue` method ,however error is prevented but script is not executing after the first error(iteration stopped on first error itself, script is not continuing ) . Need to run the script till the iteration completes     (i.e., though no values present for `[1] [status]` script should run to bring the value for next iteration element because next element may contain `[1] [status]`) 
Please help on this .
Thanks in advance

```
def inc
  begin
    page3 = `curl https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/incidents.json?page=3 -H "Authorization: OAuth a8ef42"`
    JSON.parse(page3).each do |h|
      puts "ID : #{h["id"]} , CREATED AT : #{h["created_at"]} , LINK : #{h["shortlink"]} , ISSUE NAME : #{h["name"]} , DESCRIPTION #{h["incident_updates"][0]["status"]} , DESCRIPTION #{h["incident_updates"][1]["status"]}"
    end
  rescue NoMethodError => e
  end
end
```

Comment: Instead of catching the exception, you probably want to use [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig) instead (available since Ruby 2.3).

Comment: @HolgerJust Thanks, I will also look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
def inc
  page3 = `curl https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/incidents.json?page=3 -H "Authorization: OAuth a8ef42"`
  JSON.parse(page3).each do |h|
    begin
      puts "ID : #{h["id"]} , CREATED AT : #{h["created_at"]} , LINK : #{h["shortlink"]} , ISSUE NAME : #{h["name"]} , DESCRIPTION #{h["incident_updates"][0]["status"]} , DESCRIPTION #{h["incident_updates"][1]["status"]}"
    rescue NoMethodError => e
      puts e
    end
  end
end
```

Explanation:

Whenever the exception is caught it tries to exit out of the block in which the exception has occurred.

In your previous code, you're handling it in the scope of the function. So, when the exception was occurring in the iteration it was exiting out of the loop because because it wasn't handled inside the scope in which it was occurring (loop) and was caught right outside the loop because you wrote it there (outside the loop).

To continue the iteration process you must handle it where it was occurring so that the system must know that it's been handled perfectly and it can perform the next iteration.

Comment: it worked,Thanks..seems only the code should be under `begin` though we iterating?